# Foreign Language Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, rtl

I have problem with Right to Left  /  Left to Right layout.
some languages are in (RTL) layout so i can not type exactly what i want !
provide me some help to fix this issue , please !

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has full support for RTL languages like Hebrew. If you installed Ubuntu and chose a Hebrew keyboard layout then you can switch from English to Hebrew and back using the Alt+Shift keys.

If you can't, make sure you have Hebrew keyboard layout by opening *Keyboard Layout* and adding the RTL language:

[image]

You can then choose what keyboard combination will be used to switch between languages by clicking the *Options...* buttong and setting like the below:

[image]